# What might be a reason for NullPointerException of jobLauncherTestUtils? (Spring Batch)

Tags: spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

I have a job with a step and when I attempt to test this job with JobLauncherTestUtils, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at io.spring.cdrreader.CdrReaderApplicationTests.testJob(CdrReaderApplicationTests.java:32)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
```

I have searched on net and tried many ways to solve this problem but these did not work.

Test class:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBatchTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {Config.class})
public class CdrReaderApplicationTests {

@Autowired
private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

@Test
public void testJob() throws Exception {

    JobParameters jobParameters =
            jobLauncherTestUtils.getUniqueJobParameters();

    JobExecution jobExecution =
            jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob(jobParameters);

    Assert.assertEquals(ExitStatus.COMPLETED,
            jobExecution.getExitStatus());
}
```

}

Initialization of JobLauncherTestUtils with a job in config class:

```
    @Bean
    public JobLauncherTestUtils getJobLauncherTestUtils() {

    return new JobLauncherTestUtils() {
        @Override
        @Autowired
        public void setJob(@Qualifier("demoJob") Job job) {
            super.setJob(job);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Which one is row 32?

Comment: seems like your jobLauncherTestUtils is null. Else can you specify which is line 32?

Comment: jobLauncherTestUtils.getUniqueJobParameters(); this is line 32. I think jobLauncherTestUtils is null too. But why?

Comment: That should not happen. Please share a repo with a minimal example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I have already solved this problem. Thank you for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running the test as **JUnit 4** test (see Stacktrace `com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner`), however your test is annotated with `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`, which is **JUnit 5** API.

This leads to Spring testing extensions (like `@SpringBatchTest`) not getting picked up, because the Spring extension/runner is not registered. This results in the NPE (`@Autowired` functionality doesnt work).

So you either change this to `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` or you start the test as JUnit 5 test.

Example as JUnit 4 Test:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBatchTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {Config.class})
public class CdrReaderApplicationTests {
   // ...
}
```